# Creating multiple input files by using sed in a for loop

Tags: shell-script, sed, for

Suppose I have a simple Mathematica script file named "a.m" which contains the parameter 'a' with no assigned value:

```
Solve[x^2+5^a==0,x]>>a.out
```

What I would like to do is to create multiple script files by varying the value 'a' say from 1 to 10 and name each file by the corresponding value of 'a' such as 1.m, 2.m etc.. For this, I tried to use the 'sed' command in a for loop in the following way:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do sed 's/a/i/' <a.m >i.m;  done
```

so that for each fixed value of i it would replace 'a' by the numerical value and create a new file with the name 'i.m'. However above line creates a single script file named i.m with 'a' replaced by 'i'. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `for i in {1..10}; do sed "s/a/$i/" a.m > "$i.m";  done`

Comment: (@Costas, that's a completely valid answer by the way.  Doesn't need to be a comment.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Shell scripts contain a lot of literal strings (command names, file names, etc.) so using the value of a variable requires a character to explicitly mark that it's a variable reference: [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) consists of `$` followed by the variable name (in its simplest form). [In general, you need double quotes around the variable substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). Inside single quotes, variables are not expanded at all (a `$` inside `'…'` just stands for itself). Thus:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
  sed "s/a/$i/" <a.m >"$i.m"
done
```

Inside the double parentheses, you don't need dollar signs because the double parentheses delimit arithmetic expressions, and there are no strings in arithmetic expressions so a bare word is interpreted as a variable to dereference.

Note that the sed command replaces the very first `a` character in the template file. You may want to choose a variable name that has less of a chance of occuring in something else like a function name. Alternatively, you could generate an assignment at the start of the script:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
  echo "a=$i;" >"$i.m"
  cat a.m >>"$i.m"
done
```

The redirection operator [`>>`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) appends to the existing file, in contrast with [`>`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) which truncates the file if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a mistake to call so many `sed`s where only one will do. `sed`'s claim to fame is its ability to efficiently loop over input and modify it into different output, but it can handle *multiple* outputs very easily as well. Here, for example, is a POSIX portable *(and far more efficient)* rewrite of your `for` loop:

```
echo "Solve[x^2+5^a==$((a=0)),x]>>a.out" >/tmp/i.m    ###create file + init $a
until [ "$((a+=1))" -gt 10 ]                          ###iterate + test
do    printf "h;s/a/$a/gpw /tmp/$a.m\ng;"             ###push new sed command
done| sed -nf - /tmp/i.m                              ###read + apply commands
head /tmp/[0-9].m /tmp/10.m                           ###print results
```

`sed` can read its script from stdin and apply it to a named file - which is what the `sed -nf - /tmp/i.m` statement above does. It can also simultaneously `p`rint its output to stdout *and* `w`rite its output to one or more named files. As the shell loop works it prints lines at `sed` which, when it is finished, amount to:

```
h;s/a/1/gpw /tmp/1.m
g;h;s/a/2/gpw /tmp/2.m
g;h;s/a/3/gpw /tmp/3.m
g;h;s/a/4/gpw /tmp/4.m
g;h;s/a/5/gpw /tmp/5.m
g;h;s/a/6/gpw /tmp/6.m
g;h;s/a/7/gpw /tmp/7.m
g;h;s/a/8/gpw /tmp/8.m
g;h;s/a/9/gpw /tmp/9.m
g;h;s/a/10/gpw /tmp/10.m
g
```

Which tells `sed` to...

1. Overwrite its `h`old buffer with a copy of its edit buffer.
2. `g`lobally `s///`ubstitute every occurrence of the letter `a` in its edit buffer with whatever the current value for the shell variable `$a`.
3. While also both `p`rinting the results of that `s///`ubstitution to stdout and `w`riting the results to the file named `/tmp/$a.m` where `$a` is an iterable.
4. And last to `g`et the hold buffer by overwriting the edit buffer.

`sed` will apply this sequence for every line in its named input file. When first called it will truncate each of its named `w`rite files, but will thereafter append each `w`rite action to each output file in sequence. Because I have only the one line in `i.m`, though, `sed` prints:

```
Solve[x^2+5^1==0,x]>>1.out
Solve[x^2+5^2==0,x]>>2.out
Solve[x^2+5^3==0,x]>>3.out
Solve[x^2+5^4==0,x]>>4.out
Solve[x^2+5^5==0,x]>>5.out
Solve[x^2+5^6==0,x]>>6.out
Solve[x^2+5^7==0,x]>>7.out
Solve[x^2+5^8==0,x]>>8.out
Solve[x^2+5^9==0,x]>>9.out
Solve[x^2+5^10==0,x]>>10.out
```

And `head`, reading from each of the newly created ten files in `/tmp`, prints:

```
==> /tmp/1.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^1==0,x]>>1.out

==> /tmp/2.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^2==0,x]>>2.out

==> /tmp/3.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^3==0,x]>>3.out

==> /tmp/4.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^4==0,x]>>4.out

==> /tmp/5.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^5==0,x]>>5.out

==> /tmp/6.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^6==0,x]>>6.out

==> /tmp/7.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^7==0,x]>>7.out

==> /tmp/8.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^8==0,x]>>8.out

==> /tmp/9.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^9==0,x]>>9.out

==> /tmp/10.m <==
Solve[x^2+5^10==0,x]>>10.out
```